# Pandas Groupby at least 1 of 2 columns match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with a column for Names and 2 columns for 2 possible birth years. I want to groupby the name and birthyears, if at least one of the birthyear columns match.

```
FullName     BirthYr1  BirthYr2
Smith, Joe   1985      1986
Dolan, Tom   1991      1992
Smith, Alex  1984      1985
Smith, Joe   1984      1985
Dolan, Tom   1991      1992
Smith, Alex  1986      1987
```

BirthYr2 is always 1 more than BirthYr1.

The 2 'Smith, Joe' would be grouped since they both have a 1985 (1 match), the 2 'Dolan, Tom' would be grouped since the have both columns the same (2 matches), while the 2 'Smith, Alex' would **not** be grouped since they don't have any matches.

Once I figure this out I plan on using ngroup() to assign a unique id to each group.

Answer (score 1):

This feels overcomplicated, but I think it achieves what you're looking for. Assuming your starting DataFrame is named `df`:

```
# "Melt" the birth year columns such that each value is given its own
# row. Throw away the redundant column names BirthYr1 and BirthYr2, 
# since their values are equally important to us.

melted = df.melt(id_vars='FullName', value_name='BirthYr').drop(columns='variable')                                                               
melted
       FullName  BirthYr
0    Smith, Joe     1985
1    Dolan, Tom     1991
2   Smith, Alex     1984
3    Smith, Joe     1984
4    Dolan, Tom     1991
5   Smith, Alex     1986
6    Smith, Joe     1986
7    Dolan, Tom     1992
8   Smith, Alex     1985
9    Smith, Joe     1985
10   Dolan, Tom     1992
11  Smith, Alex     1987


# Group by fullname, then birth year.

grouped = melted.groupby(['FullName', 'BirthYr']).size() 
grouped
FullName     BirthYr
Dolan, Tom   1991       2
             1992       2
Smith, Alex  1984       1
             1985       1
             1986       1
             1987       1
Smith, Joe   1984       1
             1985       2
             1986       1
dtype: int64


# Any group with more than one member represents a match.

grouped[grouped > 1].reset_index()['FullName'].unique()                                                                     
array(['Dolan, Tom', 'Smith, Joe'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This gives me some good starting points but I still need a group for everything, there would just be 2 groups for Smith, Alex.

Comment: What's your expected output?